# R Markdown - Automated Chunks?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am trying to automate chunk creation in an R markdown document. I am using the iris dataset just for this question. With this dataset there are 3 chunks, but my goal is to be able to create a document with a variable number of chunks. What I have so far is in two files - Parent.Rmd and Child.Rmd. The contents of these two files is shown below. The 3 headers are giving me what I expect. The problem is with the print(a) statement in the Child.Rmd file. It only prints the same data.frame each time, the data.frame for the last species, virginica. How do I fix this? Am I on the right track or should I be tackling this problem in another way?

Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

Paul

Parent.Rmd

---

````
---
title: "Parent"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
out = NULL
for (i in as.character(unique(iris$Species)))
{
  a <- iris[iris$Species == i, ]
  out = c(out, knit_expand(file = "Child.rmd"))
}
```

`r paste(knit(text = out), collapse = '\n')`

Child.Rmd
*********

#### Species = {{i}}

```{r echo=FALSE}
print(a)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps do the subsetting in `Child.Rmd`

````
#### Species = {{i}}

```{r echo=FALSE}
a <- head(iris[iris$Species == "{{i}}", ])
print(a)
```
````

[image: believeme]